# "The parameter is incorrect." When navigating to new pages in WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Quite often when navigating to pages in my WP7 app, I get the exception below:

I haven't been able to pin down exactly what It could be. I have implemented a lot of user controls, but I am passing the Page to each control so they may use the same Navigate call. I have also tried doing

```
(App.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame).Navigate
```

but that gives the same result often as well.

The page visually changes to the next page if the exception is handled, but the page remains on the previous page.

*For example, if I have the page layout A -> B -> C, and I get this exception navigating to C, C will appear, but I will still be on B.*

*If back is pressed, I will return to A.*

*If I interact in a way where I would go to D, I will end up on a Blank screen.*

Has anyone experienced this? I haven't seen a WP7 navigation related issue that seems to match this one.

The Parameter is incorrect.

Stack Trace:

```
  at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.SetValue(INativeCoreTypeWrapper obj, DependencyProperty property, DependencyObject doh)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.SetValue(INativeCoreTypeWrapper doh, DependencyProperty property, Object obj)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetObjectValueToCore(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueInternal(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, Boolean allowReadOnlySet, Boolean isSetByStyle, Boolean isSetByBuiltInStyle, PropertyInvalidationReason reason)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueInternal(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl.set_Content(Object value)
   at System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.CompleteNavigation(DependencyObject content)
   at System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.<>c__DisplayClass5.<NavigateCore_ContinueNavigation>b__4()
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(RuntimeMethodInfo rtmi, Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isBinderDefault, Assembly caller, Boolean verifyAccess, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeOne(Object[] args)
   at System.MulticastDelegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvoke(Object[] args)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Dispatch(DispatcherPriority priority)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.OnInvoke(Object context)
   at System.Windows.Hosting.CallbackCookie.Invoke(Object[] args)
   at System.Windows.Hosting.DelegateWrapper.InternalInvoke(Object[] args)
   at System.Windows.RuntimeHost.ManagedHost.InvokeDelegate(IntPtr pHandle, Int32 nParamCount, ScriptParam[] pParams, ScriptParam& pResult)
```

Edit:

The problem was I had code that was attempting to Navigate forward, while also attempting to navigate backwards. This caused a problem because In some situations, When in the OnNavigatedTo of the future page, my code would try to go back, only to try to go forward again. This caused a big problem.

Comment: anyway you could post a bit more of your code on how you navigate, from where, to where, with what?

Comment: willing to help here, just not enough information to help you with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you copy your project and attempt to narrow down the problem by removing all things that do not reproduce the problem. It could be a very simple problem but you have to much stuff cluttering up the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen that error occur when trying to attach a control to the visual tree that is based on an existing control, but forgeting to give it a unique name. It may be worth checking your code to see if this could happen.

Short of that, it seems to be a catch all exception relating to instantiation of controls. It may help to look for what else could be going wrong during page construction along those lines.

It would be nice if the exception could be more specific.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Just to make sure I fully understand you, do you mean not naming each element (for example leaving a textblock without a name) or having a stack which has elements that have the same name such as

Comment: <my:myControl x:Name=myControl/> on page A, and <my:myControl x:Name=myControl/> on page B?

Comment: So a control with the same Name on the same page (visual tree) is what produced the error for me last time.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I went ahead and renamed all my controls, but that didn't seem to fix it. I don't have any pages that use a control name in more than one place.

Answer (score 0):

Having looked at the code for the `NavigationService` it would seem that there is a problem assigning the destination page to the `Content` property of the `PhoneApplicationFrame`. Perhaps because of the way your are passing `Page` instances around they are not being properly removed from the frame or some other similar problem.

My suggestion would be to stop passing `Page` instances, especially as you only need access to the `NavigationService`. You could either: just pass the `NavigationService` instead, or use `PhoneApplicationFrame.Navigate`

Comment: Thanks, but the problem occurred before I tried passing a reference to the page. I was just attempting possible solutions.

Comment: OK. Could you explain what you're trying to achieve and show how you're doing that at the moment then please?